# deinit() ceases to call when this code line of code executes

Tags: ios, swift, memory, manual-retain-release

Recently I have been reviewing my code and noticed in one of my view controllers, deinit() is not called.

After commenting out this line, deinit calls successfully:

```
  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil, queue: nil)
        { notification in self.keyboardWillShow(notification: notification) }
```

I'm aware of the fact you need to remove the observer, but if I replace

```
self.keyboardWillShow(notification: notification)
```

with

```
print("hello world")
```

deinit() calls successfully.

The code inside of my local function "keyboardWillShow" is call commented out, however the function signature is

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification)
```

Any recommendations on how I can improve this code to not retain references and properly hit deinit()/

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your closure is capturing a strong reference to `self`, which prevents your object from being released; you have a retain cycle. When you don't reference `self` in the closure you avoid this cycle, which is why your view controller is released when you have just the `print` statement.

You can use `[weak self]` in the closure to prevent this; you then need to unwrap self in the closure before you use it.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil, queue: nil) 
{ [weak self] notification in 
    self?.keyboardWillShow(notification: notification)
}
```